# Why isn't the Fragment shown in Navigation?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

When starting the app, I see neither the recycle view nor the normal fragment. I'm sure that the Navigation switch the fragments but I do not see results. But when I use the saveInstantState I can get the Recycle view to work but I can't switch fragments anymore...

Any help would be great.

Main.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    MusicStoreService music;
    private DrawerLayout drawerLayout;
    private NavController navController;
    private NavigationView navigationView;
    private AppBarConfiguration appBarConfiguration;
    public MainActivity() {
        super(R.layout.main);
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        music = new MusicStoreServiceMock();

        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
// make sure you import androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar !
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        drawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        NavHostFragment navHostFragment = (NavHostFragment)
                getSupportFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.nav_host_fragment_container);
        navController = navHostFragment.getNavController();

        Set<Integer> topLevelDestinations = new HashSet<>();
        topLevelDestinations.add(R.id.productListFragment2);
        topLevelDestinations.add(R.id.helloworld);

        appBarConfiguration = new AppBarConfiguration.Builder(topLevelDestinations)
                .setOpenableLayout(drawerLayout)
                .build();

        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(toolbar, navController,
                appBarConfiguration);
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationView, navController);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .setReorderingAllowed(true)
                    .add(R.id.nav_host_fragment_container, ProductListFragment.class, null)
                    .commit();
            System.out.println();
        }


    }

    public MusicStoreService getMusic() {
        return music;
    }

}
```

main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        tools:context=".MainActivity">

        <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:elevation="4dp"
                android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways" />
        </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

        <androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:fillViewport="true"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

            <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
                android:id="@+id/nav_host_fragment_container"
                android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:defaultNavHost="true"
                app:navGraph="@navigation/nav_graph" />


        </androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
    </androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>

    <com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
        android:id="@+id/nav_view"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:menu="@menu/nav_menu"

        />
    <!-- attribute app:menu isn't mentioned in the documentation! -->
</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

menu.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item android:title="MusicStore">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/productListFragment2"
                    android:title="Products" />

            </menu>
        </item>
        <item android:title="Service">
            <menu>
                <item
                    android:id="@+id/helloworld"
                    android:title="Your Account" />

            </menu>
        </item>
    </group>
</menu>
```

nav_graph.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<navigation xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/nav_graph"
    app:startDestination="@id/productListFragment2">
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/productListFragment2"
        android:name="musicstore.fragments.ProductListFragment"
        android:label="Product List" >
        <action
            android:id="@+id/action_productListFragment2_to_mainActivity2"
            app:destination="@id/mainActivity2" />
    </fragment>
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/helloworld"
        android:name=".musicstore.fragments.helloworld"
        android:label="Your Account"
        tools:layout="@layout/fragment_helloworld" />
    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/productDetailFragment2"
        android:name="musicstore.fragments.ProductDetailFragment"
        android:label="ProductDetailFragment" />
    <activity
        android:id="@+id/mainActivity2"
        android:name="musicstore.MainActivity"
        android:label="activity_main"
        tools:layout="@layout/activity_main" />
</navigation>
```

Recycle view fragment:

```
public class ProductListFragment extends Fragment {
    RecyclerView  recyclerView;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.product_list_fragment, container, false);
        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.productlist_recycler);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        return v;
    }


    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ProductListAdapter pld = new ProductListAdapter(((MainActivity) getActivity()).getMusic(),getContext(),new ClickerListener());

        recyclerView.setAdapter(pld);
    }
```

Simple fragment:

```
public class helloworld extends Fragment {


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_helloworld, container, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: You are using a `NavHostFragment`, which means you shouldn't ever be doing any `FragmentTransaction` at all. Remove that code from your `onCreate()` entirely, it is only breaking things.

Comment: @ianhanniballake I removed the last part with the Transaction, but now it doesn't show anything anymore.